# Requiring Rails Engine Models In Referencing Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

Is there a way to automatically require models from an external Rails Engine in a Rails app without explicitly referencing the Engine's path (in my case an ugly relative path)?

I'm trying to add automatic generation of decorator for a set of subclasses defined in the engine, but BaseClass.descendants only lists descendants that have been already required.

EDIT: Some further details- I have a Rails Engine which defines a set of models:

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class FirstSubmodel < BaseModel
end
class Second Submodel
end
```

The engine is referenced in another Rails project's Gemfile, like so:

```
gem 'my_engine', path: '.../.../plugins/my_engine'
```

The Rails project needs to automatically generate decorators for each of the Submodels on initialization, like so:

```
BaseModel.descendants.each {|descendant| generate_decorator(descendant)}
```

However, 'descendants' returns an empty array since FirstSubmodel and SecondSubmodel haven't yet been loaded.

Comment: could you please elaborate with your existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using MyEngine::Engine.root, like so:

```
Dir.glob(MyEngine::Engine.root + "app/models/*_submodel.rb").each { |c| require c }
```